# how to define two primary keys Hibernate JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, primary-key

I have a class in java that has a numerical Id and username (a nature primary key).
I want to define two primary key in hibernate somthng like that with SQL

```
Create table X(
    Int ID PK,
    String name PK,
    String adress,
    .....
)
```

And i have already this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Xtable")
public class Xclass{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID_X", length=100)    
private long ID_X;



@Column(name="Name_X", length=100)  
private String Name_X;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1037)

```
@Entity
class User {
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverride(name="firstName", column=@Column(name="fld_firstname")
  UserId id;

  Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two of common approaches involve using the @IdClass or @EmbeddedId annotations:

1. Using @IdClass annotation. See http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/IdClass

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "X")
   @IdClass(XIdClass.class)
   public class XClass implements Serializable{

   ```
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Id
   private String name;

   private String address;
   //...
   ```

   }

   //1. must implement java.io.serializable
   //2. must override equals() and hashCode()
   public class XIdClass implements Serializable{

   ```
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   //accessors/mutators ...
   //override equals() and hashCode() ...
   ```

   }
2. Using @EmbeddedId annotation. See http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/EmbeddedId

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "X")
   public class XClass implements Serializable{

   ```
   @EmbeddedId
   private XEmbeddedId xPK;

   private String address;
   //...
   ```

   }

   @Embeddable
   public class XEmbeddedId implements Serializable{

   ```
   private Long id;

   private String name;
   //...
   ```

   }